# Facebook Rest API friends.areFriends IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, request, facebook-ios-sdk

How to use this method with iOS sdk? How to send parameters?

For example http request will be something like this:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/friends.areFriends?
uids1=10000179504****&
uids2=10000190198****&
access_token=...
```

Response:

```
[
{
"uid1": 10000179504****,
"uid2": 10000190198****,
"are_friends": true
}
]
```

How to remake it for obj c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a valid access token (as described in the sdk samples), you can do something like :

```
NSString *uids1 = @"10000179504****",*uids2 = @"10000190198****";

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
```

And then using the REST API :

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
uids1, @"uids1",
uids2, @"uids2",
nil];
[facebook requestWithMethodName:@"friends.areFriends"
               andParams:params
               andHttpMethod:@"GET"
               andDelegate:self];
```

Or you can also use the Graph API, as the REST API will not be supported in the future

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/friends/%@",uids1,uids2] andDelegate:self];
```

Finally, you handle the response by implementing

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result;
```

Where result should be a dictionary (it won't be the same hierarchy inside the dictionary if you use the REST API or the Graph API). Don't forget to handle the errors too ;)